# RelativeLayouts: my datalayout is stacking on top of my header layout

Tags: android, header, android-relativelayout, footer, layoutparams

im having some problemes with my layouts, i have been reading about the RelativeLayout and  RelativeLayout.BELOW is the method that should be used if you want the second child under the first one.

Here is the param code, which should show that i want header in the top, and my data layout in the middle, and then at the end i want my footer. The problem is it puts my data layout on top of my header.

```
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramsHeader = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    paramsHeader.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, RelativeLayout.TRUE);


    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramsLayout = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    paramsLayout.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, RelativeLayout.TRUE);


    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramsFooter = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    paramsFooter.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
```

after the params have been created i add them into my overall Layout (RelativeLayout).
The hsv and sv are just some scrollViews so i can scroll on the screen which works.

```
    front.addView(linearLayout);
    hsv.addView(front, frontparam);
    sv.addView(hsv);
    relativeLayoutTest.addView(sv);
    relativeLayout.addView(header, paramsHeader);
    relativeLayout.addView(relativeLayoutTest, paramsLayout);
    relativeLayout.addView(footer, paramsFooter);
    setContentView(relativeLayout);
```

I do add header before data layout and the footer.

Sorry if this seems like a dumb question but i have been reading about the RelativeLayout here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html
and i cant seem to find the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

should be

```
paramsLayout.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, header.getId());
```